# How to read data from two excel files and union all that data from into new excel file

Tags: python

I have 2 excel files with same column names . I want to UNION all that data into new excel file.

Script :

```
import pandas as pd
from xlwt import Workbook
import xlwt
book = Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

# Read the excel sheet to pandas dataframe
df1 = pd.read_excel("H:\Learning\Mohan.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
df2 = pd.read_excel("H:\Learning\Manasa.xlsx", sheet_name=0)
df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
book.save('H:\Learning\New.xlsx')
```

it is coming like this :

```
           0  1          2    3
0 2019-05-28  D 2019-05-28    Z
1 2019-05-28  A 2019-05-28    K
2 2019-05-28  B 2019-05-28    F
3 2019-05-27  A        NaT  NaN
4 2019-05-27  B        NaT  NaN
5 2019-05-27  C        NaT  NaN
6 2019-05-26  A        NaT  NaN
7 2019-05-26  B        NaT  NaN
8 2019-05-26  C        NaT  NaN
```

output :

```
     0         1    
0  2019-05-28  D 
1  2019-05-28  A 
2  2019-05-28  B 
3  2019-05-27  A 
4  2019-05-27  B 
5  2019-05-27  C 
6  2019-05-26  A 
7  2019-05-26  B 
8  2019-05-26  C 
9  2019-05-28  Z
10 2019-05-28  Z
11 2019-05-28  K
12 2019-05-28  F
```

and this out put should save into new excel file

Comment: `df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)` isn't it `axis=0` and you have it?

Comment: yes now only I have modified I have removed axis  and it got merged

Comment: @PV8 how can I transfer the result set to new excel file

Comment: `df1.to_excel('H:\Learning\Mohan2.xlsx')`

Comment: thanks @PV8 I'm completely new to python . Post it as answer I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a missspelling in your code:
`df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index=True)`has to be `axis=0` or you remove the axis, then you can export it with `df1.to_excel('H:\Learning\Mohan2.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

To merge all data from multiple Excel files, into one single file, try the concept below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import glob
glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx")

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:\\your_path\\*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
    print(all_data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
    df.shape
    df.to_excel("C:\\your_path\\final.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')
```